# register_setting not save checkbox

Tags: php, plugin-development, settings-api

To understand the Settings API I'm creating a custom settings page for a custom plugin. I have some trouble to save the settings, I have a single checkbox to test if the code works well, but if I check it and then click save button it will not be saved and didn't remain checked. What's wrong with the code? Is possible to use the `-` caratchers for the ID of a settings field or section?

```
register_setting(
      'general', // Settings section ID
      'show-countdown' // Settings field ID - maybe the problem?
    );
```

The code for the checkbox is the following.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="" id="show-countdown" name="show-countdown" value="1" <?php checked(1, get_option('show-countdown'), false); ?> />
    <label for="show-countdown"><?php echo $args[0]; ?></label>
```

NB: the `register_settings_section()` and `register_settings_field()` are working fine, this is why I omit the code.

Comment: The code you've included in the question is not sufficient for this to work, so you should include all the relevant code. Remember, it's not working and you need help to find out why, so don't leave out other code assuming it's fine.

Comment: I've checked the database, the field is saved correctly. The problem is with the third parameter of the `checked()` function that was setted on false. I've removed it and now the checkbox value is showed correctly. Thanks for the help!